# ThreadPool not starting new Thread instantly

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I have a C# Windows Service that starts up various objects (Class libraries).  Each of these objects has its own "processing" logic that start up multiple long running processing threads by using the `ThreadPool`.  I have one example, just like this:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(WorkerThread_Processing));
```

This works great.  My app works with no issues, and my threads work well.

Now, for regression testing, I am starting those same objects up, but from a C# Console app rather than a Windows Service.  It calls the same exact code (because it is invoking the same objects), however the `WorkerThread_Processing` method delays for up to 20 seconds before starting.

I have gone in and switched from the `ThreadPool` to a `Thread`, and the issue goes away.  What could be happening here?  I know that I am not over the `MaxThreads` count (I am starting 20 threads max).

Comment: That definitely shouldn't happen and doesn't happen with me. Is your console app doing anything else? If you create a brand new console app and put in `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Console.WriteLine("test"));` does it do the same thing?

Comment: Also if you want to see what the ThreadPool is doing I recommend running Process Explorer and keeping an eye on the threads in the process. You can see how many thread pool threads are being spun up. If your operations are taking a very long time to complete, it simply might take a while to ramp up to 20 threads.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ThreadPool` is specifically *not* intended for long-running items (more specifically, you aren't even necessarily starting up new threads when you use the `ThreadPool`, as its purpose is to spread the tasks over a limited number of threads).

If your task is long running, you should either break it up into logical sections that are put on the `ThreadPool` (or use the new `Task` framework), or spin up your own `Thread` object.

As to *why* you're experiencing the delay, the [MSDN Documentation for the `ThreadPool` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) says the following:

> As part of its thread management strategy, the thread pool delays before creating threads. Therefore, when a number of tasks are queued in a short period of time, there can be a significant delay before all the tasks are started.

You only know that the `ThreadPool` hasn't reached its *maximum* thread count, not how many threads (if any) it actually has sitting idle.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!  I will replace them with a Thread object and look into the Task object for future development.  Thanks!

Comment: But why does this cause the delay if there are (supposedly) free threads left in the pool? I agree with the conclusion, but do not find this answer satisfactorily answers the *why*.

Comment: @pst: You don't know that there are free threads left in the pool, you know that the `ThreadPool` hasn't reached its *maximum* number of threads. According to the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.95).aspx), the `ThreadPool` will delay creating new threads, so adding several items at once is almost guaranteed to incur a delay. See my edit. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam Robinson Much more thorough answer, +1.

Answer (score 4):

The thread pool's maximum number of threads value is the maximum number that it can create. It is not the maximum number that are already created. The thread pool has logic that prevents it from spinning up a whole bunch of threads instantly.

If you call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` 10 times in quick succession, the thread pool will not create 10 threads immediately. It will start a thread, delay, start another, etc.

<strike>I seem to recall that the delay was 500 milliseconds, but I can't find the documentation to verify that.</strike>

Here it is: [The Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> The thread pool has a built-in delay (half a second in the .NET
>   Framework version 2.0) before starting new idle threads. If your
>   application periodically starts many tasks in a short time, a small
>   increase in the number of idle threads can produce a significant
>   increase in throughput. Setting the number of idle threads too high
>   consumes system resources needlessly.
>
> You can control the number of idle threads maintained by the thread
>   pool by using the GetMinThreads and SetMinThreads

Note that this quote is taken from the .NET 3.5 version of the documentation. The .NET 4.0 version does not mention a delay.

Comment: One important thing to note is that `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` does not actually increase the number of idle threads maintained in the threadpool. It simply means that while the actual number of threads is below that number, the threadpool will create new threads on demand rather than wait for previous threads to complete.