# why my threadpool 's threads do not finish at same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, thread-sleep, queueuserworkitem

In main function  , I  write this code :

```
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(200, 200);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadWhichWillCallSQL_test), i);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
```

and thread function is like below :

```
        static public void ThreadWhichWillCallSQL_test(Object o1)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()); 
        return;
    }
```

the output is :

```
    5/25/2017 2:00:01 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:01 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:01 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:01 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:02 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:03 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:04 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:05 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:05 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:06 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:06 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:06 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:06 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:07 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:07 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:08 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:08 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:09 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:09 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:10 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:10 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:10 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:11 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:11 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:11 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:11 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:12 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:12 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:12 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:13 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:13 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:13 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:14 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:14 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:14 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:15 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:15 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:15 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:15 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:16 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:16 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:16 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:16 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:17 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:17 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:17 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:17 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:18 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:18 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:18 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:18 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:19 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:19 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:19 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:19 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:20 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:20 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:20 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:20 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:20 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:21 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:21 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:21 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:21 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:22 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:22 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:22 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:22 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:22 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:23 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:23 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:23 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:23 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:23 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:24 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:24 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:24 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:24 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:24 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:25 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:25 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:25 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:25 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:25 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:25 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:26 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:26 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:26 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:26 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:27 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:27 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:27 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:27 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:27 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:27 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:28 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:28 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:28 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:28 PM
5/25/2017 2:00:28 PM
```

you can notice that the whole process of all thread finish continue for almost 28 seconds , from my understand , these 100 thread perhaps can not finish at same time , but also can not have so much time different.

also I have set

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(200, 200);
```

and only allocate 100 threads , so should not have any thread wait for others stop ,  right ?

here is full code

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace ThreadpoolDelay
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(200, 200);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadWhichWillCallSQL_test), i);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
                Console.Read();
            }
            public static void ThreadWhichWillCallSQL_test(Object o1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: my environment is Visual studio 2012 and .net FrameWork 4.5

Comment: One can only guess, not answer, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. But, `SetMaxThreads()` does not add new active threads to the thread pool. It just sets the maximum possible. So you still have to wait for the thread pool to be populated with more threads, as your existing work items take too long. What happens if you run the test twice? Does it work like you expect the second time? _Why_ do you even care? Do you actually have a 100 core machine?

Comment: hi ,  I  do not have 100 core machine , but my machine can run 30 threads I think,when I use 30 thread to test , the earliest and latest  thread finish time still have 11 second different, I have add the full code to this post

Comment: As the question/answer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600774/threadpool-not-starting-new-thread-instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600774/threadpool-not-starting-new-thread-instantly) points out, you're looking at the wrong end. It's not that they're failing to *end* at the same time. It's that the thread pool takes time to add more threads to the pool. So they don't all *start* at the same(ish) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads are not being started at the same time in your example. Add the following call right after *SetMaxThreads*

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);
```

This will make threads start simultaneously. It's something about ThreadPool threads creating mechanics. I recommend to read [ThreadPool documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.95).aspx) for details.

To debug it more properly, update your *ThreadWhichWillCallSQL_test* method to add start time too:

```
    static void ThreadWhichWillCallSQL_test(object o1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start:"  + DateTime.Now);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("finish: " + DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Comment: Amazing , it works . yes I  do not really carefully read the document , just copy and combine  other people 's code .  thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Good Question.

Execution of the threads in thread pull depend on many factor and one of the factor is cpu core . it put thread to run in each core and once that is finished it put another.

Example:if there is 4 core cpu. It put simultaneously 4 thread in parallel and then it put next  threads as thread finish their task. mechanism is some like that not exactly ones.
    Also you put there is 5 second delay (thread sleep) so
calculation is like if there is 4 core : (30 thread/4 core )*5 some like that not exactly ones.

Also you can see there for more information :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Not really. How the pool allocates threads is an implementation detail and it may be well different for different versions. However reasonably it does NOT allocate one thread per core.

Comment: agree adrino but allocate multipal thread to core and switch context between them

Comment: Context switching? Yes, of course. and if pool allocates one thread for each request then total execution time would be around 5 seconds (ignoring any overhead). One per core? it allocates a higher number of threads, creating new threads when required according to a complex policy up to the maximum OP set. Perfect behavior for short living operations. Of course using the pool to allocate 30 long delays exploits this issue but it's simply artificial.

Comment: And when one thread is _sleeping_ the same core is used by many other threads (this is a tradeoff between affinity, good for cache, and keeping all cores busy, good for parallelism)

Comment: Thanks  Adriano Repetti for the awesome explanation